# Make Bootstrap 3 nav pills occupy defined space in grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

### Background

I am making an interface, where I show items and I use nav pills to display information.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to achieve the look I want, but my grid layout is not working as intended.

### Problem

In my interface, I want the `nav-pills` to occupy the entire space of the row they are in, but they only occupy the left corner:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills row">
    <li class="active col-sm-4">
        <a>Information</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-sm-4">
        <a>Facts</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-sm-4">
        <a>Simillar</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I read the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid), and I believe I am doing everything fine. Here is a Plunker example where you can check the mini example I provided:

- https://plnkr.co/edit/E4Fx0x8xmuy6d1TwJe9R?p=preview

### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: You read documentation for Bootstrap V4, but linked bootstrap 3.3.7 in your plnkr

Comment: I think "to occupy the entire space of the row they are in" you could try `nav-justified`: `<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">`

Comment: `nav-justified` makes each `li` occupy everything. I wand each `li` tag to occupy 4 columns out of 12 :S

Comment: nvm, `nav-justified` fixed it! (http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "to occupy the entire space of the row they are in" you could use predefined class `nav-justified`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
```